# Can we use both Google anlytics and firebase at a time?

Tags: ios, firebase, google-analytics, xcode9, firebase-analytics

I was trying to integrate the firebase analytics in my iOS app, but Xcode is throwing an issue missing tracker id, there are two GoogleService-Info.plist which I added in Xcode root directory. Many devs says to totally remove google analytics pod and use firebase analytics. But I need both. Can someone help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use both Firebase and Google Analytics when you use Firebase as datalayer for Google Tag Manager and configure GTM to send data to an GA property.

Comment: @EikePierstorff thanks for you info mate.

Answer (score 0):

I finally made it by removing pod 'google/analytics' and replacing the pod with pod 'GoogleAnalytics', and the GoogleService-Info.plist should be added to root directory of the project as well as in copy bundle resources. Both GA and firebase analytics are working.